# Open maps iphone app from my app, with pin drop at the coordinate

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I'm using http://maps.google.com.au/?ll=, to open maps iPhone app from my app, but it only show the coordinate without the pin drop automatically.
How can i make the pin to drop automatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are required to pass lat-long by appending into the URL like following way -
http://maps.google.com/?q=37.342,-122.434

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and it also works with iOS URL Scheme like comgooglemaps://?q=-43.528819,172.580481&zoom=14&views=traffic